# What font is used in commercials of CTV's new channels?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I'm trying to find what the font is for the purposes of using it myself. I guess another question would be whether the font is even publicly available/freely-usable or not. Should anyone know any freebie similar fonts, that would be nice to know as well.

Using fontfinder the closest was:
Bambino Bold by Mindburger (https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mindburger-studio/bambino/bold/)
But the "sci fi" text is completely different so that's either not right or there's multi-sets of fonts.

[image]

Here's one of their many commercials using it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0gTq8Av9Qg

Comment: If you check the CTV website and inspect the font, you will see the font used is called CTVSans Bold. AFAIK it's a custom font, which is probably not freely available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the horse's mouth, the font is called **CTV Sans** and can be found [here](https://www.cdnfonts.com/ctv-sans.font).

Comment: Well spotted! This is a custom font from Font Bureau that won't be available for licensing, that website's pirating it. You might want to look out in future for it coming on sale, often these companies get an exclusivity deal for like three years and then it's put on sale for anyone to use.

Comment: @Copilot I'm already going to hell for stealing the private font of a Bible I will refrain from mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

[Renogare Font](https://www.dafont.com/es/renogare.font), via dafont.com

[image]

**Note:** there are some differentiation between characters because each logo has some formal adjustments like the *c* in comedy and the extended *f* 's horizontal and curved stroke to get a better legibility.